# Andengine TouchEvent open new Scene

Tags: android, andengine

I need to open new Scene on Button tap, for that m using onAreaTouched method, here is my piece of code:

```
PlayBtn = new Sprite(200,35, 200,150,this.playTextureRegion){

         @Override
         public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent mmSceneTouchEvent, final float mmTouchAreaLocalX, final float mmTouchAreaLocalY){

             switch(mmSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {

                case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    playBtn = true; 
                    this.mEngine.setScene(gamePlay());  
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    playBtn = false;                                
                    this.mEngine.setScene(gamePlay());                  
                    break;

             }               

            return true;

         }           

     };
```

But here `this.mEngine.setScene(gamePlay());` line is not taken by the complier, its shows error as red mark.
So any idea can help me a lot.
Thanks.

Comment: when you hover over it does it give you a tooltip pop-up with what the error is? Where have you declared mEngine? I am not familiar with andengine, but if you post a bit more of the code around this I might be able to help. I suspect that the "this" you are using is the Sprite object, and that your mEngine reference is actually something that you created in a higher context.

Comment: yeah what Tim said - might help us to see what gamePlay() does as well - specifically, if it doesn't return a "scene"

Comment: no i did not got anything such...i have tried with toast message to see the button responses or not ,that work as well and tried by simple calling the my game scene as gamePlay() instead of "this.mEngine.setScene(gamePlay());" but no luck...

Comment: Yah gamePlay has to return a Scene...gamePlay is Scene itself       public Scene gamePlay(){
      
       this.mEngine.registerUpdateHandler(new FPSLogger());
         GamePlayScene = new Scene();       
       daybgAnimatedSprite = new AnimatedSprite(0,0,800,512,daybgTiledTextureRegion);         
       daybgAnimatedSprite.animate(new long[]{100,100,100,100,100,100},0,5,true);            
         
         GamePlayScene.attachChild(daybgAnimatedSprite);      
         
         return GamePlayScene;
}

Comment: You HAVE to tell us what the error is. When you place the cursor over the red mark, a little message should show. What does it say? I checked your code of gamePlay() and it seems to be OK.

Answer (score 0):

I think this link provide you more guidance about how to manage scene in the single activity.
https://sites.google.com/site/matimdevelopment/creating-and-managing-scenes

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling a method called "gamePlay()". Rather, you need to be calling a Scene.
So, what you do is within your gamePlay() method, you declare a new Scene, and then call it. Example below.

```
// Your Method called gamePlay()
public void gamePlay(){

myNewScene = new Scene();

// Set up your scene here. Background, Sprites, Text etc.

}
```

// Change Scene to myNewScene here on pressing the playBtn

```
playBtn = new Sprite(200,35, 200,150,this.playTextureRegion){

         @Override
         public boolean onAreaTouched(final TouchEvent mmSceneTouchEvent, final float mmTouchAreaLocalX, final float mmTouchAreaLocalY){

             switch(mmSceneTouchEvent.getAction()) {

                case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    playBtn = true; 
                    this.mEngine.setScene(myNewScene);  
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    break;
                case TouchEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    playBtn = false;                                
                    this.mEngine.setScene(myNewScene);                  
                    break;

             }               

            return true;

         }           

     };
```